# How to enable admission controller on a GKE cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

I'd like to investigate an issue with `nginx-ingress` on a GKE cluster. Therefore I need to enable admission controller and was wondering whether this is possible on GKE. I'm creating the cluster with

```
[authentication boilerplate]
gcloud container clusters create cluster-name --machine-type=n1-standard-1 --no-enable-stackdriver-kubernetes --no-enable-autoupgrade --preemptible
```

I find no option in `gcloud --help` or `gcloud container clusters create --help`.

I need to enable the admission controller for service accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use gcloud beta like this:

`gcloud beta container clusters create [CLUSTER_NAME] --enable-pod-security-policy`

Or you can use update:

`gcloud beta container clusters update [CLUSTER_NAME] --enable-pod-security-policy`

[**This page**](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/pod-security-policies) explains how to use PodSecurityPolicies in Google Kubernetes Engine.