# How to enable DefaultStorageClass admission controllers on a GKE cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

There are some great [admission controllers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/) such as [DefaultStorageClass](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#defaultstorageclass), StorageObjectInUseProtection, PersistentVolumeClaimResize that enfoce some k8s best practices to your
cluster.

In order to enable admission controller you must have admin access to the k8s api-server, but on GKE you don't have.

So how we can enable these admission controller in GKE?

Note: I saw few related questions raised in the past but with no answers like [question3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59103316/how-to-enable-admission-controller-on-a-gke-cluster) and [question4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62696739/how-to-enable-podnodeselector-admission-controller-plugin-in-gke).

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to modify enabled admission controllers, as that would require modifying the `--enable-admission-plugins` API server configuration option, and that is not possible on GKE, nor are there any alternative ways to set this option at the moment.

Now, looking at each of the individual controllers mentioned:

- **DefaultStorageClass** - this admission controller is enabled in GKE. You can check that the standard pre-created storage class has the `storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"` annotation. In order to use different SC as default, remove this annotation from the standard  storage class, and add it to the SC of your choice.
- **StorageObjectInUseProtection** -  this admission controller is enabled in GKE, you can observe that that `kubernetes.io/pv-protection` and `kubernetes.io/pvc-protectionfinalizers` are added to PVs, resp. PVCs, in use, preventing their deletion.
- **PersistentVolumeClaimResize** - this admission controller is also enabled in GKE. You can verify this by creating a storage class with `allowVolumeExpansion: false` annotation [1](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/volume-expansion) (note the standard SC does allow expansion), create a PVC and try to increase it's size. You'll receive an error such as:

  ```
  error: persistentvolumeclaims "my-pvc" could not be patched: persistentvolumeclaims "my-pvc" is forbidden: only dynamically provisioned pvc can be resized and the storageclass that provisions the pvc must support resize
  ```

At last, if you would want to enable a controller that is actually not enabled on GKE, you would need to reimplement and deploy this as a standalone service into your cluster and use K8s' *ValidatingWebhookConfiguration* or *MutatingWebhookConfiguration* to connect K8s API your service via webhook [2](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/). Apart from implementing this from scratch, there are many projects that can help, OPA Gatekeeper [3](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/gatekeeper) and Metacontroller [4](https://metacontroller.app/) to list some examples.